# I'm using GET CLI in flutter and everthing is working fone except for this command "get generate model on home from "https://randomuser.me/api/"

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, get-cli

I've installed the GET CLI flutter on my windows machine and everything seems fine. Also, I've just created a few projects using that. But when I use this command

> get generate model on home from "https://randomuser.me/api/"

then I'm getting this error from the terminal in the vs code

```
get generate model on home from "https://randomuser.me/api/?result=10"
```

Calls one batch program from another.

CALL [drive:][path]filename [batch-parameters]

batch-parameters   Specifies any command-line information required by the
batch program.

If Command Extensions are enabled CALL changes as follows:

CALL command now accepts labels as the target of the CALL.  The syntax
is:

```
CALL :label arguments
```

A new batch file context is created with the specified arguments and
control is passed to the statement after the label specified.  You must
"exit" twice by reaching the end of the batch script file twice.  The
first time you read the end, control will return to just after the CALL
statement.  The second time will exit the batch script.  Type GOTO /?
for a description of the GOTO :EOF extension that will allow you to
"return" from a batch script.

```
    %~dp1       - expands %1 to a drive letter and path only
    %~nx1       - expands %1 to a file name and extension only
    %~dp$PATH:1 - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable for %1 and expands to the
                   drive letter and path of the first one found.
    %~ftza1     - expands %1 to a DIR like output line

In the above examples %1 and PATH can be replaced by other
valid values.  The %~ syntax is terminated by a valid argument
number.  The %~ modifiers may not be used with %*
```

This is the version of my Get-cli
[image]

What is the issue here? Maybe that can be some windows issue. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

change the api from
https://randomuser.me/api/?result=10

to
https://randomuser.me/api?result=10

Change that have been done is : remove the '/' after the term 'api'

and then use the command to generate model

get generate model on home from https://randomuser.me/api?result=10

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).